# Google Spreadsheets ArrayFormula: How to split and transpose a cell-range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello everybody and thanks a lot for your help.
Here's my problem:

**What I have:**
I have a table with raw data in 53 rows and numerous columns which I would like to reduce and restructure into three columns: City, Date and Value.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bsdC8lrtSGk957ae8Z0VRGnDqTZfFLPpLkfoid0UbIQ/edit?usp=sharing
**What I've done so far:**
For a single row, I used the following formula to make everything work as I wanted it to:

```
ArrayFormula({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(Base_Data!A2)&"|"&TRANSPOSE(Base_Data!AJ1:1&"|"&Base_Data!AJ2:2),"|")})
```

**What I want:**
I'd like to extend the formula to work for the entire area, all 53 rows. Does anyone have a tip for this? The solution doesn't have to be a formula, it would work as a script, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up a new sheet called "New_Data [Erik]" and placed the following formula into A2:

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Base_Data!A2:A&"\"&Base_Data!AJ1:1&"\"&Base_Data!AJ2:54),"\",0,1))
```

If this is a one-time conversion, I'd recommend copying the results in place. To do that, select A:C, hit Ctrl-C to Copy and then Ctrl-Alt-V to Paste Special. A small clipboard icon will appear. Click it and choose "Paste Values Only."

If you'll need this functionality ongoing, just understand that FLATTEN is a not-yet-official function of Google Sheets, which means that while Google sheets may very well make it official, they may *also* decide to do away with it at any time. (This is why I suggest copying and pasting the results in place, if it's just a one-time conversion.)

Comment: Thanks Erik, thats exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately it is an ongoing datasheet, but I will try it anyway. Thanks a lot!

Comment: FLATTEN is such a useful formula, I do hope Google officially adds it soon. Worse case, if they yank it, just come back here and someone will offer another solution. There are ways to do it without FLATTEN; they just make formulas quite long.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to get to there. If you are trying to leave out all columns but 3, just do `={Base_Data!A2:A, Base_Data!E2:E}` and add as many columns as you require comma-separated within the curly brackets

Comment: Thanks! I thought there might be a way to just use a range like `Base_Data!A2:A` and `Base_Data!AJ2:54` so I'd get all dates as rows + their values for every city.